# Berlin, Germany building data set

Tags: data-request, images, germany

I am working on building foot print comparison.  I would like to know the open data sets available to compare.

I found the OSM  data from goefabrik: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin.html

Comment: Can you specify which characteristics the datasets should have, especially in comparison to the OpenStreetMap data?

Comment: @ojdo i did not define the characteristics yet, as i am exploring the open data set of only OSM through their `/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“building”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building”
  node["building"]({{bbox}});
  way["building"]({{bbox}});
  relation["building"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;` in https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Answer (score 4):

For Berlin you can get data from the Berlin OpenData Portal: https://daten.berlin.de/

Here is the Dataset with the Buildings: https://daten.berlin.de/datensaetze/alkis-berlin-geb%C3%A4ude-wfs

At this moment the Link looks broken, but i found this WFS Service, which should contain the same data: 
`http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/berlin/service.jsp?id=s_wfs_alkis_bauwerkeflaechen@senstadt&type=WFS` (WFS Capabilies: `http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis_bauwerkeflaechen?service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities`)

If you compare to OpenStreetMap data, you should look if parts of the OSM-Data is imported from the official Data from the OpenData portal